# Styling BaseFormSet.can_order with a class

Tags: django, forms

How do I style BaseFormSet.can_order or BaseFormSet.can_delete with a class. Where do I place the widget definition?

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional fields to a formset covers styling of fields like this.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/